Python threads 'starved' by pandas operations
I am creating a UI application with Qt in Python. It performs operations on pandas DataFrames in a separate threading.Thread to keep the UI responsive; no individual pandas instruction takes noticable time. However, there still is a lag of around around a second in the MainThread.
I heard of the global interpreter lock (GIL), but as far as I understand, it should be released after a few milliseconds. When the separate Thread has already been executing for a whole second, why does it still execute more Python instructions? How do I get rid of the lag properly?
I found out that if I sprinkle time.sleep(0.00001) throughout the separate thread, the lag is gone. But this can't be the solution.
If I use some other heavy computation without pandas (only tried other operations implemented completely in Python), there is no delay in the MainThread.
I reproduced the problem in the following script. The highest deltaTime for me is around 1 second, whereas with the commented sleep it is around 0.1s.
import threading
import time
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

longest_so_far = 0
last_timestamp = datetime.now()
first_run = True


def print_delta_time(interval=0.001):
    global longest_so_far
    global last_timestamp
    global first_run
    while True:
        time.sleep(interval)
        current_time = datetime.now()

        if first_run:
            first_run = False
        else:
            delta_time = (current_time - last_timestamp).total_seconds()
            if delta_time > longest_so_far:
                print("New longest deltaTime:", delta_time)
                longest_so_far = delta_time
        last_timestamp = current_time


def perform_pandas_operations():
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Starting pandas operations")
    df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A': [f"{i}" for i in range(1000)],
    })
    for _ in range(20000):
        df['A'].str.contains(r'123$').sum()
        # time.sleep(0.0000001)
    print("Finished pandas operations")


pandas_thread = threading.Thread(target=perform_pandas_operations)
pandas_thread.daemon = True  # Ensure the thread exits when the main program exits
pandas_thread.start()

print_delta_time()


I ran your code and got New longest deltaTime: 0.099899 right before the pandas operations ended. You're getting longest_so_far > 1 second?

When running it many times, the average longest deltaTime is around 0.9s, I think.
New longest deltaTime: 0.001
New longest deltaTime: 0.00103
New longest deltaTime: 0.001038
New longest deltaTime: 0.001532
New longest deltaTime: 0.001534
New longest deltaTime: 0.001536
New longest deltaTime: 0.001562
Starting pandas operations
New longest deltaTime: 0.007511
New longest deltaTime: 0.091737
New longest deltaTime: 0.092209
New longest deltaTime: 0.664877
New longest deltaTime: 0.899437
New longest deltaTime: 1.450165
Finished pandas operations

I made the same observation for a numpy/scipy case (running minimize in a separate thread). If the CPU thread runs uninterrupted, it can starve the Tkinter thread arbitrarily long. At least under Windows (did not try in Linux yet).
The solution is indeed to do a near-zero-time sleep. This seems to signal to the scheduler that the Thread can be suspended and other Threads have a chance to run. Of course this requires that you have at least some "breakpoints" where you can put that call.
Actually, you can use this for beneficial effects:

You can replace time.sleep by threading.Event.wait, and use the event as "Cancel"-Flag, to allow interruption of calculation.
Also, this is the perfect breakpoint to update a progress bar or other display :-)

